# Uploading files with Node

Tags: node.js, file-upload, restler

I'm building a Node API wrapper and would like to give the user the ability to upload a file from their local drive to the server. I'm using the [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler) library for making REST requests and the core logic for uploading a file is shown below:

```
_post = (apiurl, "/path/to/file.pdf", cb) ->
  rest.post(apiurl,
    username: "username
    password: "password"
    data: "/path/to/file.pdf"
    multipart: true
    ).on "complete", cb
```

But when I make the request, the below error is thrown:

```
{ errors: [ { message: 'Error downloading file from URL' } ] }
```

However, I am able to complete regular POST requests when there's no file to be uploaded. Any suggestions?